# R's lm(), get x when y is known

Tags: r, regression, inverse-prediction

Here is some data and a logarithmic model:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:8,
  y = c(7.5,6,5.2,4.3,3.9,3.4,3.1,2.9)
)

model <- lm(y ~ log(x), data = df)
```

I am able to use this model to predict y for any given x e.g.

```
predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x = 10)) # 2.3
```

My question is, if I want to find y when x is known, can I do that? 'Reverse prediction' or what's the correct term?

e.g. If I want to know the value of x when the function output is 8, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm assuming that whoever closed this pasted the wrong duplicate link, because I don't see how that linked post answers the question.

Comment: This is called calibration or [tag:inverse-prediction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)       log(x)  
      7.544       -2.268
```

In original

$$y=7.544-2.268 \cdot \log(x)$$

therefore

$$(7.544 - y)/2.268 = \log(x)$$

or

$$\exp((7.544 - y)/2.268) = x$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I've heard it referred to as [calibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration_(statistics)) or inverse regression. Hope that gives you something to start.

Comment: Thanks for the info @PRZ!